# How many stereoisomers are possible for 1,2-dimethyl-4-(propan-2-ylidene)cyclopentane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers, cis-trans-isomerism

> How many stereoisomers (not counting different conformers) does 1,2-dimethyl-4-(propan-2-ylidene)cyclopentane have?
>
> [image: Structure of 1,2-dimethyl-4-(propan-2-ylidene)cyclopentane]

I think the answer should be 3. There are two geometrical isomers (*cis* and *trans*) considering the two methyl groups on the ring, and the *trans* isomer will also show optical isomerism as it doesn't have a plane of symmetry. But in my book, the answer is given as 2. Is this a misprint?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87848/discussion-on-question-by-franshu-how-many-stereoisomers-are-possible-for-1-2-d).

Answer (score 6):

In this structure the left hand methyl groups can be on the same side of the ring. This is one stereoisomer. This molecule is not chiral and there is only one isomer with the methyl groups on the *same* side of the ring.

Initially I assumed that there was only one other isomer: the two methyl groups on the *opposite* side of the ring. But building models sometimes wrecks intuition. The picture below shows the **two** possible version with *trans* (relative to the plane of the ring) methyl groups:

[image: All possible stereoisomers of 1,2-dimethyl-4-(propan-2-ylidene)cyclopentane]

So my initial view was wrong: the molecule is chiral and that gives three total stereoisomers.

Comment: Yes, not threo and erythro, but meso and d/l, [slide](http://wps.prenhall.com/wps/media/objects/340/348272/Instructor_Resources/Chapter_23/Text_Images/FG23_04.JPG)

Comment: If you know your tartaric acids, you know this one.