# Total number of stereoisomers of 1,2-dimethyl-4-(propan-2-ylidene)cyclopentane

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

[image]

I don't think there is any change of showing geometrical isomerism across the double bond because the two groups on the right side (two $\ce{-CH_3}$) are the same.

Also I don't think there should be optical isomerism as there is plane of symmetry. Can someone please explain the solution?

Comment: There might or might not be a plane of symmetry. This whole thing is not planar.

Comment: are there any atoms which are chiral centres?

Comment: @H.Linkhorn I don't think so

Comment: Would the two carbon atoms joining the two butyl branches together be chiral. It is a different route to get back to the double bond depending which way you go.

Comment: The two methyls on the left can be on the same side of the 5-membered ring or on opposite sides. This generates two *distinct* compounds.

Comment: Maybe it would help to add the hydrogen atoms to the structure like in this [related structure](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.484463.html). For the related structure on chemspider, you can click on the 3D link to rotate it to examine the geometry at each carbon.

Comment: Question identical to [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/107432/how-many-stereoisomers-are-possible-for-this-compound)

Comment: @matt_black Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @matt_black what about the enantiomers of the trans configuration?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Am I correct in saying that a plane of symmetry will be present in the same side configuration as pointed out by matt_black?

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN What trans configuration? It isn't geometrically possible.

Comment: @matt_black Can you please show with perhaps figures what you are talking about? It would be more helpful ;-)

Comment: @tatan Why don't you think there is a plane of symmetry here? There could or could not be depending on the stereochemistry at the two chiral centers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar molecule to illustrate: [image]

Two of the ring carbons are asymmetric (chiral). This molecule itself (as shown) is chiral. If you change one of the chiral carbons, you get a molecule that is not chiral (mirror plane along the double bond and perpendicular to the ring).

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Can you please mark the carbons with a paint tool etc. and make a reference to which particular carbon you are refering to...

Comment: Thanks for commending my effort. Could you check the rules for chiral carbons, and do it yourself?